# C++ Passing current object to free function

Tags: c++

This might be a simple question, but I'm having trouble passing the 'current object' into a free function that takes it as an argument.

Here's a simple example that illustrates my problem.

I have a Cat class, and an external function "createCatMeme" that creates a meme based on a Cat object. But if I want a Cat object to "react" to a meme of itself, and react is a Cat method, how do I pass the current Cat into "createCatMeme"?

```
class Cat
{
    std::string name;

    Cat() {...}

    inline react(Meme meme) {...}

    inline reactToOwnMeme()
    {
        Meme meme = createCatMeme(/* How do I pass in the 'current' Cat object? */);
        react(meme);
    }

};

Meme createCatMeme(const Cat& c);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do I pass the current Cat into "createCatMeme"?

Use `*this`.

```
inline reactToOwnMeme()
{
    Meme meme = createCatMeme(*this);
    react(meme);
}
```

However, to do that, `createCatMeme` must've been declared before the function definition.

I noticed that `reactToOwnMeme` dos not have a return type.

#### Option 1

Declare the function before the class definition.

```
// Forward declare the class.
class Cat;

// Declare the function
Meme createCatMeme(const Cat& c);

// Define the class.
class Cat
{
   ...

    inline void reactToOwnMeme() // Assuming void as return type.
    {
        Meme meme = createCatMeme(*this);
        react(meme);
    }
};
```

#### Option 2

Declare the function after the class definition. For this to work, the member function has to be defined outside the class definition.

```
// Define the class.
class Cat
{
   ...

    // Declare the member function
    void reactToOwnMeme();
};

// Declare the function
Meme createCatMeme(const Cat& c);

// Define the member function
void Cat::reactToOwnMeme();
{
    Meme meme = createCatMeme(*this);
    react(meme);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!